# i can get the button to call the function but cannot call from the if statement set off by the search but can call any other function just fine

Tags: javascript

// this function works from the button not from the search

```
function initialize2() {// google maps load function
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    marker.setMap(map); // set marker
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); // initializ map
```

// this button works fine

```
<div id="sscbc">
    <div id="ssi"></div>
    <div id="sscb">
    <button onclick="initialize2()">Enter ID</button> // loads map with marker
    </div>
</div>
```

// this does not work

// function for testing search values and calling function based on results any function will work here except the function im trying to call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function doSearch() {
            searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value 
            if (searchvalue == "1") {
                initialize2();
            }
            else {
               alert("no good");
            }
        }

</script>
```

// search form

```
   <div id="searchwrapper">
    <form name="searchbox">
        <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="searchterm"/>
        <input type="image" src="images/opacbox1.png" class="searchbox_submit" value="Search" ONCLICK="Javascript:doSearch()" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

// full code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>


<head>


<title>
</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">


<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=true">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position:myLatlng, title:"Hello World!"});

var map = null;

function initialize() 
{

    var mapOptions = 
        {

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771),

        zoom: 12,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        disableDefaultUI: true,


    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


    //  marker.setMap(map);



}

function initialize2() 
    {

            var mapOptions = 
        {

                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771),

            zoom: 12,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            disableDefaultUI: true,

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        marker.setMap(map);

    }   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<head>



<body>

<div id="map-canvas"/>

</div>

<button onclick="initialize2()">Enter ID</button>

<form name="searchbox">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" name="searchterm"/>
<input type="image" src="images/opacbox1.png" class="searchbox_submit" Id="imageButton" value="Search" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function doSearch(e) 
    {
            var elem = document.getElementsById('imageButton')[0];

            elem.addEventListener('click', doSearch);


        e.preventDefault();


                searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value 

        if (searchvalue == "1") 
        {
                    initialize2();
                }
        else 
        {
            alert("no good");
        }   
        }


</script>

</body>



</html>
```

// css

```
body

{
      }

#map-canvas 
{ 
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

#searchwrapper 
{
    width:310px;
    height:40px;
    background-image:url('images/searchbox6.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
}

#searchwrapper form 
{ 
    display: inline; 
}

.searchbox 
{
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    left:9px;
    width:256px;
    height:28px;
    color: #fff;
}

.searchbox_submit 
{
    border:0px; /*important*/
    background-color:transparent; /*important*/
    position:absolute; /*important*/
    top:4px;
    left:265px;
    width:32px;
    height:28px;
}
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default behavior of the form. As by default the form submits when a button inside is clicked

Comment: im not sure how to prevent the defualt behavior of the form to get my desired result any suggestions or samples?

Comment: and im pretty confused why if i write any other function the if statement has no problem calling it. it just cannot call the google maps api function. im new to there api so i assume it has to do with the function.

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();`

Can't add comments yet.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default action of the `Form` . Also do not define inline events as it is a bad practice. Bind your events in the script directly, so that you can separate out the structure with the functionality.

**HTML**

```
<div id="searchwrapper">
    <form name="searchbox">
        <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="searchterm"/>
        <input type="image" src="images/opacbox1.png" class="searchbox_submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
 </div>

<div id="sscbc">
    <div id="ssi"></div>
    <div id="sscb">
    <button onclick="initialize2()">Enter ID</button> // loads map with marker
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('searchbox_submit')[0];

    elem.addEventListener('click', doSearch);

       function doSearch(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value 
            if (searchvalue == "1") {
                initialize2();
            }
            else {
               alert("no good");
            }
        }
</script>
```

Similarly attach the events to the other button as well.

### **UPDATE**

**HTML**

```
<!-- Did not close the div properly -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Added an id for the button -->
<button id="button1">Enter ID</button>

<form name="searchbox">
    <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="searchterm" />
    <input type="image" src="images/opacbox1.png" class="searchbox_submit" Id="imageButton" value="Search" />
</form>
<!-- Did not close the form properly -->
```

**Javascript**

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatlng,
    title: "Hello World!"
});

var map = null

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    function doSearch(e) {
        // The 2 lines below have to be moved out of the function
        // As this is the place where you are binding the event
        // So this function will never be called when event is not attached
        ///var elem = document.getElementsById('imageButton')[0];
        ///elem.addEventListener('click', doSearch);
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value
        if (searchvalue == "1") {
            initialize();
        } else {
            alert("no good");
        }
    }

// This was calling initialize2 
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize2);
// You can directly call initialize and there is 
// no difference between initialize and initialize2

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// Attach the event to the button
var button = document.getElementById('button1');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    initialize()
});

// Attach the event to the Image 
// Was var search = document.getElementsById('imageButton')[0];
// It is getElementById without the s
// Remember that ID is unique so no plural
// But className and tags are plural
// SO you have a s in them
// Also index is not required
var search = document.getElementById('imageButton');
search.addEventListener('click', doSearch);

// Call the function so that map is initialized when called
// You can also attach this to the window load event if you want
initialize();
```

**[**Check Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5DHRF/)***

Comment: Error: Unable to get value of the property 'addEventListener': object is null or undefined

Comment: There was a small typo in the code I have written `elems.addE` should have been `elem.addE` .. Had an extra `s` .If you have multiple elements with the same class then give a `ID` to the element. And select the element using `document.getElementById('id')`

Comment: Try using an id instead

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByID'

Comment: and why is this the only function that does not work with my original if statement?

Comment: by the way i really appreciate your help and taking the time to try and help me through this.

Comment: the whole point of this is to add markers to a google map that correspond with the input in the search field using a switch statement im just trying to get the basic concepts understood if theres a better way to go about it im all ears.

Comment: Should be `getElementByID` .. You have an extra `s`

Comment: does the search form refresh the page after its run the function?

Comment: Error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Comment: right. exactly.. As the button inside the form when clicked with post the form and you want to avoid it

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried.. And also the `HTML` that you changed

Comment: <div id="searchwrapper">

   <form name="searchbox">
    <input type="text" Id="searchbox2" name="searchterm"/>
    <input type="image" src="images/opacbox1.png" class="searchbox_submit" value="Search"" />
   </form>
  </div>

 </div>


</div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  var elems = document.getElementById('searchbox2_submit')[0];

    elems.addEventListener('click', doSearch);

       function doSearch(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            searchvalue = document.searchbox2.searchterm.value 
            if (searchvalue == "1") {
                initialize2();
            }
            else {
               alert("no good");
            }
        }
</script>

Comment: You have not given a `ID`  to the `<input type="image"` .. So when you try to find by id it returns undefined..

Comment: Try Adding a id `<input type="image" id="imageButton" `

Comment: sorry about the formatting brand new to this site just learning the mechanics

Comment: Your script will now look like `var elem = document.getElementById('imageButton'); elem.addEventListener('click', doSearch); `

Comment: I have used `[0]` for class names as there can be multiple elements with the same class.. So that acts as an index to get the element. But id is unique on the page. So it will always return a single element

Comment: same error, so if i understand correctly we are trying to keep the button value at 0 so no refresh happens and add a listner on click for text input in the search bar to run the function on?

Comment: i found another post about stopping the refresh action on the form im looking over now

Comment: Can you paste the whole script and HTML in the question again you are trying with below the original question.

Comment: @user2643840 - Please add the html to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18005514/edit), rather than one of the answers. If it is too large to post here, consider using pastebin or gist. Then update your question with a link.

Comment: @user2643840 .. Move your script to just before the closing tag of the body.. Then assign a `id` to the `<input type="image" id="imageButton"` And assign the event in the script instead of inline events and remove the `onsubmit` attribute as well

Comment: reedited both css and html to a cleaner simpler form still works to post marker with button and not with search bar one after making your suggested changes no longer have the else statement functioning you can load both in blank files and see the same results i am removed all images so they wont affect testing it out.

Comment: if anyone can get this to post a marker with the search bar input of one i would be estatic

Comment: ive tried everything i can think of for the last eight hours and found several posts that have suggestions for killing the refresh of the searchbox but no one seems to solve it i posted the code under full code load it and try if you think its possible.

Comment: not sure but maybe i can use a diffrent object to get the same result? take the input from a text box and ma if it passes the statement run the function without a page refresh?

Comment: @user2643840.. Check updated post.. I have added a little bit of explanation in the code that I posted.. You can place the whole javascript in a single script block and place it just before the end of body..  A better method is placing the whole code under the script block inside a `js` file and include it just before the closing tag

Comment: simple answer $("#cpa-form").submit(function(e){
    return false;
});

Comment: it worked with my original code flawlessly couldnt quite understand what we were trying to accomplish here but you helped me understand why it wasnt working which lead to my answer stop the form from reloading the page.

Comment: actually that was a false started getting strange action upon further investigation an unclosed tag caused the problem and was just not refreshing but not returning the right values too read more into it and found that by adding onsubmit="return false" to my form tag it stopped the page refresh and fixed everything.